# jquery datepicker format date issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have jquery date picker implement trough Shared/EdotorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml like this

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"),
   new { @class = "date" })
```

obviously I want dd.mm.yyyy date format. Everything is ok when form is first loaded.

But, I'm getting mm/dd/yyyy format on jquery datepicker. I tried with following on _Layout.cshtml on domready with

```
$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.MM.yyyy" });
```

but I'm getting these strange date `11.September.20122012`

How to fix these to dd.mm.yyyy format?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit like this

```
$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" });
```

Comment: You dont need to specify that year has 4digits,so give it as "yyyy",it simply "yy"

Answer (score 0):

$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.MM.yyyy" }); it will display date as 11.September.2012

$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }); it will display date as 11/09/2012

`$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });` it will display date as 11-09-2012